# How to hide a row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got 10 records from the database so I just need to click on hide button then the particular row will be hidden not all data but in my code when I click on hide button then all data will be hidden. here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $(".hide_material").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>Material Name</th>
  <th>Qty/Piece</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
  <td>
    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row->qty; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $total; ?>
  </td>
  <td><button type="button" id="btn" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: All 10 rows with a button with `id="btn"`? Invalid HTML

Comment: Surely there is no point using `toggle` as once it is hidden, you cannot click it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `$(this).closest(".hide_material").show();`

`.closest()` is your friend, It will look for the first parent element that has the class `.hide_material`

Since you are hiding the row that contains the button, use `.show()` and not `.toggle()`

As Pete said, you should be careful with having the same id on multiple elements, The ID should always be unique.

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hidebtn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".hide_material").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Material Name</th>
      <th>Qty/Piece</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide_material">
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->name; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->qty; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $total; ?>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="hidebtn btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's edited now but earlier your were also using .toggle() :)

Comment: Please don't be rude. I just gave my opinion.

Comment: Please don't delete your comments now and you are downvoting my answer :). My answer is exactly matching the requirement. I think we instead of being rude we should work together as good and mature community members. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @VicJordan If we should work together, why is you jump around commenting on small mistakes if you don't spend the time on fixing your own? Duplicating ID is a major no no

Comment: Great! you agreed that there was mistake in your answer which I pointed out. I just mentioned it and I didn't downvoateeven but I upvoted your corrected answer. Duplicating IDs? As far as I know it was his just sample code not complete code. If he has given complete 10 rows code in that case I must have corrected that also but here he just wanted to hide a row. That's it. And ofcourse my code will work for multiple rows as well.

Comment: please read the Code of Conduct. Thank you very much: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @VicJordan Sample code or not, if an inexperienced user comes here, He might think that duplication id is okay.

Comment: Please don't go with assumptions **He might think that...**
My answer doesn't deserve downvote if not upvote. I am going to flag you because it is not in compliance  with the Code of Conduct of community. I am using SO from a quite long time and this is first time I faced such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggle();
    //Use Alternative
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>Material Name</th>
  <th>Qty/Piece</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
  <td>
    sadasd
  </td>
  <td>
    dasd
  </td>
  <td>
    asdas
  </td>
  <td><button type="button" id="btn" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There is no use of using `toggle()` as you can perform toggle again i.e. can't show the row again. It's better to use `.hide()`

Comment: @VicJordan same reason here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).closest('tr').toggle();`. You are also using id as `btn` for listening click event. You can use `.hide_material button` without using `id` value.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hide_material button").click(function () {
      $(this).closest('tr').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Material Name</th>
    <th>Qty/Piece</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>   
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" id="btn" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" id="btn" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" id="btn" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no use of using `toggle()` as you can perform toggle again i.e. can't show the row again. It's better to use `.hide()`

Comment: @VicJordan I have answered based on OP's context. There may be possibility that this is just a part of a entire code where `toggle()` make sense

Answer (score 0):

Use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method of jQuery to hide it as you just need to hide it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hide_material button").click(function () {
      $(this).closest('tr').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Material Name</th>
    <th>Qty/Piece</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>   
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide_material">
 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->qty; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
 <td><button type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:25px; " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Show/Hide</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: An ID should always be unique, So allowing `id="btn"` multiple times is just bad!!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I am not using `id` to handle click event so that `id` doesn't has any impact on hiding `tr`. It was just sample code not more than that. If you find it incorrect, I have removed it. Please check my answer now. Thanks